# How to return map values into an object [] seperated with commas

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi guys I'm try to return the values of an object into another object (Not sure if that make sense).
So basically what I'm doing is mapping over an object like this:

```
series:this.state.summaryData3[0].summary.population.gender.values.map((value) =>{
 return [value]
})
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
series: [54,46]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `.map()` returns an array, so instead of `return [value]` you want just `return value` right?  As it is, you end up with an array of arrays.

Comment: There is no reason to return a single array, just returning value gives you an array.

Comment: If you just want to copy the array, use `….slice()` or `Array.from(…)`.

Comment: Omg! it was so simple, didn't knew that :(. Thanks both of you !

Comment: if `....gender.values` is an array of values, just say `...gender.values.slice();`. Although, i guess if you feel compelled to use `.map()`, you can say `...gender.values.map(value => value);`

Comment: Thanks for all of you answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a shallow copy an array, you can use `.slice()`:

```
series: this.state.summaryData3[0].summary.population.gender.values.slice()
```

---

If you wanted to modify each value in the array as you make a copy, you could use `.map()` and return the new value (not in an array) from the callback.  The `.map()` function will collate all the returned individual values into a new array and return that new array:

```
series: this.state.summaryData3[0].summary.population.gender.values.map(function(item){
    // some modification of the original value
    return item + 1;
});
```

Note, there is no reason to use `.map()` if you are just returning the same value.  If you just want the original value, then just use `.slice()` to make a copy.  And certainly don't return an array unless you want an array of arrays as the result.

---

And, if all you need is a reference to the existing array itself, you don't even need to make a copy:

```
series: this.state.summaryData3[0].summary.population.gender.values
```

---

So, you have three different options here depending upon your specific requirements.